# How can I make a screen shot of a Window behind my Form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi, bitmap, window

My app runs in front of a Google Chrome Window. The right hand quarter of the chrome window is always visible as I may need to interact with it. The left hand side of the chrome window is completely covered as this is where my controls are.

The trouble is, there are a couple of things on the left side of the Chrome Window which might change from time to time, and I need to know when this happens. It would look really messy to make transparent areas on my form, so what I need to do is shoot a graphic of the chrome window behind my form every few seconds so I can check for any differences.

I have found numerous examples of code using `bitblt` etc but so far all I'm getting is solid black. Nothing is returning any image. So how can I shoot a graphic of the Chrome Window?

If anyone could provide a function which returns a bitmap from a `hwnd`, that would be brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, give `PrintWindow` a try.

This function issues a `WM_PRINT` or `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message (depending on the flags specified), so the Window that receives and processes the message prints itself to the `hDC` passed in the function call.
► The Window can be completely obscured by another, it doesn't matter, it's not a screenshot. The Window has to process the message, though.

---

The static (`Shared`) **`RenderWindow`** method shown here, returns a Bitmap object generated by the [PrintWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow) function.

You should try to pass `True` as the `clientAreaOnly` argument, to set `PW_CLIENTONLY` as the `nFlags` option, because many WPF apps are designed to hide the default Window Frame, while WinForms Windows usually don't, so try to pass `False` in this case.

The optional `tryGetFullContent` argument sets the **`PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT`** flag, which is available from Windows 8.1+. This flag is not documented.
**UPDATE:** in this case, it's what gets the job done.

To get the Handle of the Window you care about, you have many options.

`Process.GetProcessesByName("processName").FirstOrDefault(...)` or `Process.GetProcessById(id)`, if you know the Process Id.

Or [FindWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexw), or [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows), or [EnumDesktopWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdesktopwindows), depending on the context.
See here: [How to obtain task bar Notification Area width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52572859/7444103) for a simple use of the `FindWindowEx` function.

Assuming you have a WinForms app, you can call the method like this, to show a Bitmap of the rendered Window in a PictureBox:

```
Dim proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD").FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero)
If proc IsNot Nothing Then
    PictureBox1.Image = RenderWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, True)
End If
```

**Win32 Declarations and implementation of the RenderWindow method**:

► Here, I'm using [DwmGetWindowAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute), specifying `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` as the attribute, to retrieve the Window rectangle.
You could also use [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect), but this function is not DpiAware (and a bit old :), it may return a wrong size in specific conditions.

```
Public Shared Function RenderWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, clientAreaOnly As Boolean, Optional tryGetFullContent As Boolean = False) As Bitmap
    Dim printOption = If(clientAreaOnly, PrintWindowOptions.PW_CLIENTONLY, PrintWindowOptions.PW_DEFAULT)
    printOption = If(tryGetFullContent, PrintWindowOptions.PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT, printOption)

    Dim dwmRect = New Rectangle()
    Dim hResult = DwmGetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, dwmRect, Marshal.SizeOf(Of Rectangle)())
    If hResult < 0 Then
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hResult)
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim bmp = New Bitmap(dwmRect.Width, dwmRect.Height)
    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Dim hDC = g.GetHdc()

        Try
            Dim success = PrintWindow(hWnd, hDC, printOption)
            ' success result not fully handled here
            If Not success Then
                Dim win32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                Return Nothing
            End If
            Return bmp
        Finally
            g.ReleaseHdc(hDC)
        End Try

    End Using
End Function
```

**Native methods:**

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Friend Shared Function PrintWindow(hwnd As IntPtr, hDC As IntPtr, nFlags As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("dwmapi.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Friend Shared Function DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd As IntPtr, dwAttribute As DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE, ByRef pvAttribute As Rectangle, cbAttribute As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Public Enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE As UInteger
    DWMWA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED = 1      ' [get] Is non-client rendering enabled/disabled
    DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY           ' [set] DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY - Non-client rendering policy
    DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED    ' [set] Potentially enable/forcibly disable transitions
    DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT                ' [set] Allow contents rendered In the non-client area To be visible On the DWM-drawn frame.
    DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS        ' [get] Bounds Of the caption button area In window-relative space.
    DWMWA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT         ' [set] Is non-client content RTL mirrored
    DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION  ' [set] Force this window To display iconic thumbnails.
    DWMWA_FLIP3D_POLICY                ' [set] Designates how Flip3D will treat the window.
    DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS        ' [get] Gets the extended frame bounds rectangle In screen space
    DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP            ' [set] Indicates an available bitmap When there Is no better thumbnail representation.
    DWMWA_DISALLOW_PEEK                ' [set] Don't invoke Peek on the window.
    DWMWA_EXCLUDED_FROM_PEEK           ' [set] LivePreview exclusion information
    DWMWA_CLOAK                        ' [set] Cloak Or uncloak the window
    DWMWA_CLOAKED                      ' [get] Gets the cloaked state Of the window
    DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION        ' [set] BOOL, Force this window To freeze the thumbnail without live update
    DWMWA_LAST
End Enum

Public Enum PrintWindowOptions As UInteger
    PW_DEFAULT = 0
    PW_CLIENTONLY = 1
    PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT = 2
End Enum
```

Comment: I had really high hopes for your function when I saw it Jimi - unfortunately it just returns a solid black bmp just like all the other methods I have tried! Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Actually this seems to be a problem with Google Chrome. It works with other windows, actually so does bitblt, but nothing seems to work with a chrome window, just returns a black area each time.

Comment: UPDATE: I found a way to make this work with the chrome window! It is necessary to use tryGetFullContent, i.e. Dim bmp = RenderWindow(hwnd, False, True). Using clientAreaOnly doesn't work with chrome windows! Thank you for you help Jimi, got there in the end!