# PrintScreen and BitBlt causing screen flicker

Tags: c#, winapi, bitblt, printscreen

I'm trying to take a screenshot of another window specified by a valid hwnd. The procedure works, however the window flickers when the screenshot is taken.

The first function uses PrintScreen, the second BitBlt. Each is called from a routine that takes a screenshot every 10 seconds.

Is there a way to avoid a flicker when using the PrintScreen or BitBlt functions?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
        public Bitmap GetScreenshot(IntPtr ihandle)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = ihandle;//handle here

        RECT rc;
        FocusWindow(ihandle);
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Right - rc.Left, rc.Bottom - rc.Top, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        IntPtr hdcBitmap;
        try
        {
            hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        bool succeeded = PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);
        gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
        if (!succeeded)
        {
            gfxBmp.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
        }
        IntPtr hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
        GetWindowRgn(hwnd, hRgn);
        Region region = Region.FromHrgn(hRgn);//err here once
        if (!region.IsEmpty(gfxBmp))
        {
            gfxBmp.ExcludeClip(region);
            gfxBmp.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        }
        gfxBmp.Dispose();
        return bmp;
    }
        public Bitmap CaptureWindowImage(IntPtr hWnd)  //, System.Drawing.Rectangle wndRect)
    {
        IntPtr hWndDc = GetDC(hWnd);
        IntPtr hMemDc = CreateCompatibleDC(hWndDc);
        RECT rc;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rc);

        IntPtr hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWndDc, rc.Width, rc.Height);
        SelectObject(hMemDc, hBitmap);

        BitBlt(hMemDc, 0, 0, rc.Width, rc.Height, hWndDc, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hWndDc);
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hMemDc);
        DeleteDC(hMemDc);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: you should just use `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`. I see a few GDI memory leaks in your code. That's not causing the flicker, but there are zero reasons to use unmanaged code for this solution, especially if you use it wrong.

Comment: BTW, `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` already uses BitBlt internally. -- As an alternative, you can also call [PrintWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow); example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65317047/7444103) (slightly different language). It has the advantage that is not a screenshot, so you can print a Window to a destination DC even if its partially or completely obscured by another.

Comment: Are `GetScreenshot` and `CaptureWindowImage` two methods? When I used `CaptureWindowImage`, I didn't find any flickering problems. Did I miss some steps? Which window does the flickering problem appear on? Maybe you can post the complete code for us to reproduce.