# How to capture a snapshot of a specific window in WinForms without capturing any other windows that hover over it

Tags: c#, winforms, user32

Unable to capture a snapshot of a specific window in WinForms. I have tried to capture the WinForms window specifically. However, it captures the snapshot along with portions of other windows.

I have tried to capture the WinForms window using the GetForegroundWindow() function from the User32 DLL to find the handle, and then I have used the Graphics.CopyFromScreen method to capture the content of the window specified by the windowHandle. However, it captures the snapshot along with portions of other windows.

```
 internal BitmapSource TakeScreenSnapshot(IntPtr windowHandle)
        {
            User32.RECT bounds = GetWindowBounds(windowHandle);
            Thickness padding = GetWindowClientArea(windowHandle);
            
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)bounds.Width, (int)bounds.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen((int)bounds.left, (int)bounds.top, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
                }

                IntPtr hBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();
                try
                {
                    return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
                }
                finally
                {
                    User32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                }
            }
        }
```

[MainWindow image with other window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOYcI.png)

Comment: [Print an image of the content of a Panel excluding any external overlapping Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68895127/7444103) -- [How can I make a screen shot of a Window behind my Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65317047/7444103)