On Windows 11, why does my app's window still get resized when I set the DPI awareness context to DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2?
I've created a skeleton Windows app using Visual Studio 19's app creation wizard. At the start of WinMain(), I call
SetProcessDPIAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);
and in WndProc(), I add handling for WM_DPICHANGED, where I return immediately (ie I don't call DefWindowProc() in that case).
I then change the display scale from 100% to 150% using the Settings app.
From what I understand, with this setup, the dimensions of my app's window shouldn't change when I do this, but when I print the results of GetWindowRect() to the console before and after the scaling change, different values are printed. The values that are printed match what Windows suggests in the LPARAM of WM_DPICHANGED - in other words, it seems that Windows is automatically scaling the window dimensions.
Also, when I try the exact same app on a Windows 10 PC, I don't see any dimension change, as expected.
Does anyone know what might be going on here?
Thanks.

Please be more specific about what you expect and what's actually happening.  If your application does claim to understand high-DPI, then, when the scaling factor is significantly larger than 96 dpi, Windows will lie to it and scale the window's contents on as though all painting assumes 96 DPI.  But scaling the contents is distinct from resizing the window.  I don't think it's surprising that the window manager might resize (and even reposition) windows when all the screen metrics change.

DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 actually means the opposite (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows):
"When an application reports to Windows that it wants to run in this mode, Windows will not bitmap stretch the application when the DPI changes, instead sending WM_DPICHANGED to the application window. It is then the complete responsibility of the application to handle resizing itself for the new DPI. "

When Windows sends WM_DPICHANGED, it provides a Rect in LPARAM that the application should use to resize its Window (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged):
"In order to handle this message correctly, you will need to resize and reposition your window based on the suggestions provided by lParam and using SetWindowPos. If you do not do this, your window will grow or shrink with respect to everything else on the new monitor. "

Since the purpose of WM_DPICHANGED is to allow the application to resize and reposition the window, I expect that if I ignore (and don't handle) this message, that the window shouldn't be resized when I change the DPI scaling... however it seems that it still is.

It's possible that WM_DPICHANGED is useful for resizing and repositioning child windows.  For top-level windows, however, I think it's mostly just a chance to know the DPI has changed.  In my answer, I explain why the top-level window appears to change size and position even though its window rectangle does not.

Still unclear on what you're seeing and how that differs from your expectations, I used the VS App Wizard and made the changes you described:

Set the process's awareness context to DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 at the beginning of wWinMain.

Return 0 on WM_DPICHANGED to indicate the message has been handled and to prevent the DefWindowProc from moving or resizing the window.


Additionally, I changed the code to:

Create the window at a specific position (100, 100) and size (640 × 480).
Display the values of the screen and client rectangles in a WM_PAINT handler
Display the horizontal and vertical DPI as reported by the most recent WM_DPICHANGED
Draw two rectangles, one at 96 × 96 and the other at 1 inch × 1 inch per the DPI reported by the most recent WM_DPICHANGED message.

Observations:
When I change the "Scale and layout" percentage:

The window rectangle does not change.  It remains at (100, 100) and the size is still (640 × 480).  Remember that the Window rectangle is in virtual screen coordinates.  Either those are DPI independent or, as with all of the DPI Awareness Contexts, it's locked for your process when you create the first window.

The window's apparent size and location does change—slightly.  The window rectangle includes the resizing border, even though modern versions of Windows no longer show it (which still trips me up every frickin' day!).  When the scale factor changes, the system computes new metrics.  As the scale factor increases, the thickness of the invisible border around all four sides of the window increases, so the visible portion does get smaller and slightly offset horizontally.

When I change the window style to exclude WS_THICKFRAME, the apparent size still decreases as the scale factor increases. This surprised me.  My hypothesis is that, even though you can no longer click and drag on the invisible border pixels to resize the window, the system still reserves them in order to draw the drop shadow on three sides of the window.


The last two points are confirmed by creating two windows that are just touching and noting that there appears to be space between them.


Thanks a lot for doing that test. It seems that I get different results. If I create the window at position 100, 100 and size 640x480, at 100% DPI scaling, then if I check the result of GetWindowRect(), it returns position 100, 100, size 640x480 as expected. If I then change the DPI scaling to 125%, the window noticeably increases in size, and GetWindowRect() returns position 100, 100, and size 800x600... which isn't what I was expecting.

I think you may be mistaken about the Windows APIs returning virtualised coordinates regardless of the DPI awareness context though.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows:
"Registering a process as running in PMv2 awareness mode results in:
The application seeing the raw pixels of each display"
And also this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060280/getting-an-dpi-aware-correct-rect-from-getwindowrect-from-a-external-window

If I recall, Windows high-DPI scaling for legacy apps didn't kick in until the DPI was significantly higher than 96 DPI, like maybe 144?  I don't know if that's still the case or whether there are remnants of that in the current scaling world, but there could be.  Going from 100% to 125% might not be significant enough to demonstrate the behavior.  I typically run at 175%, so most of my tests started there, then dropped to 100% and I sometimes took it as high as 200 or 250%.

I'm not sure, but I see the same odd behaviour even when changing from 100% to 175% (the maximum my setup allows).
Also, as I mentioned in the question, I don't see this behaviour at all on my Windows 10 PC, only on my Windows 11 one, so that seems strange too.

I was surprised that changing the scaling factor made absolutely no difference to the coordinates of the window rectangle with DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2.  Some of the descriptions for the context awareness options talked about checking the DPI when a window is created and then adjusting the scaling factor (but not scaling the window) if the DPI changes.  The documentation is confusing and, in places, seemingly inconsistent.  It was my best explanation for the values I was getting.

Ah, I'm on Windows 10.
